# Data is not being sent with URL by HaylLtd / cordova-background-geolocation-plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm using HaylLtd/cordova-background-geolocation-plugin for tracking. The plugin is hitting the server, but sending no data (postTemplate) with it. Here's my configuration. Platform cordova-android@12, Targetting android@13, Testing on android@12. Everything is working well, but not sending data along with the URL.

**The configuration: **

```
`BackgroundGeolocation.configure({ 

locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER,
desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
debug: true, 
url:'http://198.198.5.166/abc/controller/TestMethod',
postTemplate: { 
lat:'@latitude',
 lon:'@longitude' 
} 

});`
```

**The log:**
POST /domain/controller/TestMethod - 80 - 195.178.8.99 Dalvik/2.1.0+(Android+12;) - 500

**The log with Postman:**
POST /abc/controller/TestMethod/ postTemplate=[lat:22,lon:32] 80 - 194.188.3.231 PostmanRuntime/7.33.0 - 500 0 0 27150

I have tested the API with Postman and it's working well. What I expect is; the plugin should send/attach the data along with the URL.

The log with Postman:
POST /abc/controller/TestMethod/ postTemplate=[lat:22,lon:32] 80 - 194.188.3.231 PostmanRuntime/7.33.0 - 500 0 0 27150